# What Ubuntu distribution should I install?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I got a PC with the following configuration:

Intel Core2Duo 2.6Ghz
4GB of RAM DDR2 667
Nvidia 7200GS 256mb

The graphics card is the weak point of my computer. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 but the graphics effects we're running very slow, although the rest was working well. Now I installed Lubuntu and everything it is running ok but I think it is too simple, I would like a distribution more like Ubuntu.

What Ubuntu distribution can you recommend me for my configuration ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using elementary (elementaryos.io). If your machine is daily drive I would suggest against freya.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Ubuntu Mate?

[image: Ubuntu MATE Screenshot]

Download it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Ubuntu Studio:  http://ubuntustudio.org/
It sports a low latency kernel, so it gets the most out of your hardware!